# Reduce delay when Serial communicate between Arduino and Python

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

While communicate between Arduino and Python using Serial communication, Python program need to wait a second or more as fallowing code:

```
import serial as ser


prt = ser.Serial(
port='COM18',
baudrate=9600,
parity=ser.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=ser.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=ser.EIGHTBITS
)


while 1:
    prt.write(str(0) + '\r\n')
    time.sleep(1) #I want to reduce this time
    prt.write(str(1) + '\r\n')
    time.sleep(1)
```

This code has `sleep(1)`. It stuck my Python program for one second.I want to remove or reduce this time.I tried to 0.9,Arduino not responding correctly.

This is my Arduino program:

```
#define led 13

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
byte incomingByte;

if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  incomingByte = Serial.read();
  switch (incomingByte) {
    case '1':
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      break;
    case '0':
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
      break;
    }

  }

  }
```

How can I reduce or remove this delay?
Why need a delay(more than 1 second) after every sending?

Comment: what do you mean 'arduino not responding correctly'? Be precise. What else is it doing? What else is the Pi doing? you are outputting three characters, that should only take about 3ms to send, so you should be able to get the sleep down to 0.005 and it should still work - but you may have difficulty seeing the LED flash at that rate - 100Hz.

Comment: Can you configure the Arduino to use a faster baud rate? 9600 is pretty standard but is also really slow. 115200 is pretty commonly used these days in my experience, but I don't know Arduino.

Comment: @barny I send '0' and '1' from Python application and Arduino read '0' or '1' and if read is '1' LED must on and if read is '0', LED must off.
I have added 1 second delay after every sending.
This is the whole function of above codes.However, if I reduce delay time after sending '0' or '1', LED is not blinking.

Comment: @CivFan .. Arduino can use more baude rate.But As I know it decided transmission speed. Transmission speed is not a problem in this system. Problem is why need a delay(more than 1 second) after every sending?

Comment: *"However, if I reduce delay time after sending '0' or '1', LED is not blinking."* -- Negative descriptions such as *"not blinking"* do not convey salient information.  Also the list of negative descriptions is almost infinite: it didn't blow up, it didn't make any sounds, etc. IOW did the LED stay on or did it stay off?  Or did it blink so fast that you can't detect the blink rate?

Comment: *"Why need a delay ... after every sending?"* -- Such a delay is often a crude/ignorant method of delaying for the write operation to complete (aka *draining*, which should not be confused with *flushing*).

Comment: Get the Arduino to echo exactly what it receives, does it do that quickly? BTW there is no need to put \r\n on the sent character, that's just noise as far as the Arduino is concerned.

Comment: Did you try running `prt.flush()` after the write?

Comment: @CivFan yes..Problem is solved after adding `prt.flush()` 



Thanks everyone for your valuable advice ..

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Arduino to send a short (1-2 bytes) message after receiving of each incoming message, the so-called acknowledge. And on the raspberry side after each sending you wait for this confirmation and do not send anything until you'll receive an acknowledge from the Arduino. This technique is used in many consumer and industrial serial protocols.

You can also increase the data transfer rate if you want. However, be careful with speeds over 115200. If you use long unshielded wires, then the connection may be unstable.